# Overriding deprecated UIKit methods -- Can I get a warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

Apple sometimes deprecates methods in UIKit that you are expected to override (e.g. [UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] in iOS 6).

Unfortunately, once you change your deployment target to the version where it's fully deprecated, there is no warning/error produced even though the method is deprecated and will never be called...ever.

If you CALL a deprecated method, you get a warning, but not if you override one.

I'd like to be able to find all my deprecated methods I'm overriding so I can clean them out over time.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks,
-Vince

Answer (score 0):

You should have build warnings about using deprecated functions.

There's an article here on making sure they are enabled in Xcode, but it is quite old:
http://blog.mro.name/2010/06/xcode-missing-deprecated-warnings/

Here's an Xcode 4.5 screen shot:

[image: Here's a screenshot from Xcode 4.5 when the Project -> Target is selected:]